# Cannot Restore My Previous Salesforce Authenticator Account to My New Phone

Tags: heroku, salesforce

I don't know how to restore the previous account I don't see any options to reconnect the previous account to my new phone. I just want to know how to reconnect the already connected heroku+salesforce account to my  phone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRFe.png)
I was expecting to have reconnect to your authenticator app option with qrcode or phrase.